# Navigation between interface in PyQt and python

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qt-designer

I want to navigate between forms: when I click on a button to go to a new interface, the current one closes automatically (if I am in the "Sign In" interface and I clicked on a button to go to the "Sign up" I want the "Sign In" in to close), but the problem I face is that the function does not seem to work: both the interfaces are still open.

```
    def openwindow(self):
        self.nextui = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = login.Ui_Login_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.nextui)
        self.nextui.show()
```

[image]

I tried to add `MainWndow.hide()` to the code but the function does not seem to work: the error I got when I added `MainWndow.hide()` is:

```
Error! Error due to 'Ui_Login_Dialog' object has no attribute 'hide'
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante i add an image show what happen and i tried to clarify what i want i hope you understand it

Comment: I didn't ask for an image, but for a MRE. Please carefully read that link and provide what's been requested. Besides, either you're not using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), or you're using them wrong: the left side of that dialog should have fields properly aligned, and they clearly are *not*. Finally, you shall never, **ever** try to edit pyuic generated files, instead follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).